# Rails: Ordering objects created in 3 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display the hottest posts in 3 days, so this is what I do

`@posts = Post.created_in_days(3).order_by_likes.first(4)`

For queries:

```
scope :order_by_likes, -> { order('likes IS NULL, likes DESC') }
scope :created_in_days, ->(number)  {where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - number.days)}
```

This works fine. But the problem is, sometimes there is not enough `posts` generate in 3 days. Maybe just 3, or even no post at all.

How can I handle this so when `@posts` created in 3 days is not enough, it would extend the time, till it get enough `@posts`? (In this case, `4 post` needed).

Comment: can u explain how extending time should work?

Comment: @rahulv Well, just to get `post` created in 4 days or 5 days, till it get enough `@posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :created_in_days, ->(number) do 
   filtered = where('created_at >= ?', Time.zone.now - number.days)
   if filtered.length < 4
      order(:created_at => :desc).limit(4) # takes last 4 created
   else
      filtered
   end
end
```

Comment: But how could I reorder this into `like` order? It seems like it doesn't chain with other scope method.